# OS X 10.5.8 Mobile Account with Active Directory

Tags: macos, mac, active-directory, folder-redirection

I've got a Mac Mini client joined to an SBS 2008 box.  I'm using SMB shares in the domain.  The Mac has been binded to AD, I can log in with any user account.  It even asks me if I want to create a Mobile User if a new user logs in.

I would like to setup the Mac to have Folder Redirection that works like our Windows clients.  So have the Documents folder redirect to the My Documents redirected folder, Pictures with My Pictures, and so on.  If I can avoid using symlinks, that would be great.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using network folders? Have you looked into MCX Redirection?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding MCX Redirection.  At the moment, it looks like that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on implementing virtually the same set-up.  I've got Windows 2008 R2 running AD and supporting Windows 7 and Mac clients.  Haven't *completely* solved everything you want here, but I've certainly made a start.

There's a very useful doc from Apple - ["Best Practices for Integrating OS X Lion with Active Directory"](http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_integrating_active_directory.pdf) which helped me a lot.  Basically you need to extend the Active Directory schema with all the relevant data for the mac.

You need to create a file with the appropriate schema changes (I called it `apple_update.ldf`), then:

1. Log into the server using a role with FSMO (Schema Master) rights (My Administrator account worked for me)
2. Go to the PowerShell
3. Save out the current schema (for backup)

> ldifde -f backup_file.ldf -d "cn=schema, cn=configuration, dc=domain, dc=root"

4. Now apply the changes (e.g. for MyDomain.com)

> ldifde /j . /k /i /f apple_update.ldf /v /c "DC=X" "DC=MyDomain,DC=com"

5. I then used Apple's workgroup manager to set up my syncing preferences for the macs.  You'll probably want to turn off syncing for a lot of items in the `~/Library` folder as you'll otherwise find that folder synchronisation takes ages.

You can then use Group Policy on the server to define folder redirection for "Documents" and "Desktop".  I've got this working and can log-on on either a Windows machine or a Mac and see files created / updated on the other.

I haven't yet solved this for other folders, such as "Pictures" etc.  I've got policies set up on the server and they work on the PC clients, but not on the macs so far.  If I get a solution here, I'll update my post.

I should also point out that logging on to the mac in offline mode is *very* slow if you have no connection to the server, but do have an internet connection - probably due to a lot of network time-outs.  I haven't found a cure for this yet, other than to disconnect completely so the mac knows it's working offline.